# Loop infinito em Evento

Tags: c#, eventos

Tenho uma classe chamada Dta que contém o seguinte código:

```
public event Dta._TimeOutEventHandler _TimeOut;

public delegate void _TimeOutEventHandler(Dta dta);


public void CheckTimeOut()
{
    if (TimeOut == null) {
        TimeOut = new Timers.Timer();
        TimeOut.Interval = 10000;
        TimeOut.Start();
        TimeOut.Elapsed += TrateTimeOut;
    } else {
        TimeOut.Stop();
        TimeOut.Start();

    }

}

private void TimeOut()
{
    TimeOut.Stop();
    if (_TimeOut != null) {
        _TimeOut(this);
    }
}
```

Em outra classe chamada Monitor, verifico se ocorreu o evento timeout da classe Dta com o seguinte código:

```
_TrateTimeOut += new Dta._TimeOutEventHandler(EncerraPorTimeOut);
```

No entanto quando o método EncerraPorTimeOut é chamado ele entra em um loop infinito.

```
private void EncerraPorTimeOut(){
   Console.WriteLine("Metodo Encerrado por TimeOut");
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar também o método `EncerraPorTimeOut` na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Com loop infinito você quer dizer que o evento do Timer é disparado várias vezes e você quer que seja disparado apenas uma?

Em `CheckTimeOut`, se definir que `TimeOut.AutoReset = false;` o handler do `Elapsed` vai ser chamado apenas na primeira vez que o seu evento de timeout acontecer.

Answer (score 0):

Tá esquisito este código. O correto seria disparar o `Timer` com `Enabled`, e `Elapsed` receber um `Handler` tipado, no caso, `ElapsedEventHandler`, assim:

```
public event ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed;

public void CheckTimeOut()
{
    if (TimeOut == null) 
    {
        TimeOut = new Timers.Timer();
        TimeOut.Interval = 10000;
        TimeOut.Elapsed += Elapsed;
        TimeOut.Enabled = true;
    } else 
    {
        TimeOut.Stop();
        TimeOut.Start();

    }
}
```

Em `Monitor`:

```
Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(EncerraPorTimeOut);
```

E `EncerraPorTimeOut` fica assim:

```
private static void ElapsedEventHandler(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Metodo Encerrado por TimeOut");
}
```